# How to create a bash script to execute non-headless automation in python-behave

Tags: python, bash, selenium, bdd, python-behave

I asked this few days back but it was assumed and erroneously linked to a previous question. This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861992/how-to-create-a-bash-script-to-execute-non-headless-chromedriver-python-behave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually simple.

I found a workaround by using `export headless=0; behave` in the non-headless bash script and it worked.

The caveat to this method is that I have to use `os.getenv('headless')` which refers to the value set in my .env file. that was headless=1.

The final webconfig.py looks like this.

```
import dotenv

import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

dotenv.load_dotenv()

headless = bool(int(os.getenv('headless')))


class Driver:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

        if driver == "chrome":
            if headless:
                chrome_options = Options()
                chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
            else:
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        elif driver == "firefox":
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        else:
            print(f"{driver} is not defined.")
```